# What is the mean "--disable-extensions" of chromedriver option?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver

Does "--disable-extensions" mean **Disable Chrome Extension** (plugins)?

Like below:
[image: m]

Or another mean that I found on stackoverflow:

**Disable the developer extensions.
The chromedriver that is automatically running an extension called Chrome Automation Extension.**

But I don't understand what is Chrome Automation Extension?

How does it impact Chrome when I use automation script with chromedriver?